# mql4 function with array: error parameter conversion not allowed

Tags: mql4

I created this function and put it above init() but got error parameter conversion not allowed, I don't understand why :

```
int BelongsToArray(int value, int[] array)
{
    int arrSize = ArraySize(array);
    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        if(value == array[i])
        {
            return true; // value belongs to array
        }
    }
    return false; // value does not belong to array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function only accepts integer type array, but in the body of your code, you must have given it an array that is not an integer type (such as `double`) as input. So, to find the cause of the error, refer to the places in your code where you have called this function (that is, `BelongsToArray`).

Also in the function argument part, the second input, the array must be passed by reference. Therefore, it should be corrected as follows:

```
int BelongsToArray(int value, int &array[])
```

I have a suggestion. Because the output of the function is boolean, it is better to use `bool` instead of `int` in the header of the function. However, if this is not done, the code will still work correctly.